# Как наложить один элемент разметки на другой?

Tags: android, xml

Хочу наложить к примеру , помню получалось как то можете помочь.
Есть вот код нужно элемент `avatar` наложить на `circle` (чтобы он был поверх него)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/start_click"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Tag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tag, import"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для налоложения виджетов используется контейнер `FrameLayout`, который размещает все виджеты от левого верхнего угла, если не указано гравити (или `RelativeLayout`, если позиционирование более сложное)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/start_click"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

  <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/circle"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_default_material_light"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Tag"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="tag, import"
            android:textColor="@color/primary"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Для простых случаев можно использовать решение из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527333/177345)

Comment: вы всегда первые! :)

Answer (score 1):

`FrameLayout` это контейнер для отображения одних View поверх других. Примерный код такой, разберетесь сами.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/circle"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/list_item_avatar_size"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />
```