# Наложение изображения на изображение в Android

Tags: java, android, изображения, imageview, android-imageview

Нужно наложить на изображение , получаемое из интернета, изображение кнопки youtube. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: используя какой нибудь `RelativeLayout` или же сделать кастомный `ImageView`

Comment: Првильно говорит @ermak0ff - просто создайте блок с относительным выводом, задайте два ImageView - один для картинки из интернета, другой - для Вашей кнопки YouTube. И задайте второй картинке координаты нужные над первой картинкой.

Comment: Вам нужно что то типа превью со значком Ютуба в углу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким образом

items.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/items"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mini_img"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

getView() в GridViewImageAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(activity);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
    } else {
        grid =  convertView;
    }

   ImageView imgMain=(ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.main_img);
   ImageView imgMini= (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.mini_img);
    AppConstants.setImage(activity,position,imgMain,imgMini,AppConstants.mThumbIds);

    imgMain.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imgMain.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth,
            imageWidth));
    imgMain.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));

    if(AppConstants.mThumbIds[position].getIsVideo()) {
        imgMini.setPadding(0, 0, 8, 0);
        imgMini.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imgMini.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                activity.getResources(), R.drawable.youtube16));
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать особенность `ImageView` по которой для этого виджета можно указать и содержимое и бэкграунд в виде изображения, чтобы совместить их.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:background="@drawable/thumb"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Здесь
*icon* - изображение какого-либо значка (должен иметь прозрачный бэкграунд)
 *thumb* - изображение картинки.
Параметр *adjustViewBounds* должен быть установлен, для того, чтобы картинка вписывалась в размеры виджета.

Если для значка требуются какие то отступы или другое позиционирование, можно использовать что то вроде `LayerList` и подобные [Drawadle Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) предоставляющие возможность задать положение для изображения. Например, сдвинуть значок на 50dp влево и вниз.

создаем ресурс: res/drawable/icon.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/icon"
        android:left="50dp"
        android:top="50dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

К примеру, поместить их в `FrameLayout`

Картинку из интернета первой, Ваше изображение кнопки youtube вторым и в итоге оно будет накладываться на первое.

Comment: Изображения сами у меня должны отображаться в GridView. В этом вся сложность для меня, я не могу понять, как в одной ячейке можно отобразить `FrameLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй воспользоваться классом `LayerDrawable`, который при создании объекта параметром контструктора принимает массив из нужных вам Drawable:

```
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(drawableList);
```